# Match multiple conditions for a long method call without repeating it

Tags: ruby

I'm wondering if there is a better way to handle multiple matches on longer method calls than repeating the long call in a piped statement. Example:

```
if value == ''
  return nil
elsif class.method[:key].select(id: id).first.nil? || class.method[:key].select(id: id).first == 1
  return nil
end
```

Ideally I'd like to one line this since it returns the same result, so the if/elsif is useless, but I'm not sure if I can match `.nil?` and `== 1` on the same thing without repeating it or setting it as a variable beforehand.

Comment: While this question is answerable, it would be better in future to post a code snippet that is a minimal reproducible example, and that is fully executable *as posted*. That's not the case with the code you posted, so while you may get useful answers the code will either be untested or force respondents to formulate classes, methods, or data to fit their answers. This is always sub-optimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your code otherwise works as posted, you can do what you want by storing the result of the chained method in a variable before performing your comparisons. For example:

```
return nil if value.empty?

result = class.method[:key].select(id: id).first
return nil if result.nil? || result.eql?(1)
```

The semantics here will do what you expect without having to repeat the method chain. There are certainly other ways to express the idea, such as a case statement, but this should do what you expect in a very compact way.

Comment: Note that the empty expression evaluates to `nil`, so `return if value.empty?` and `return if result.nil? || result.eql?(1)` are equivalent to what you wrote. I am not sure whether one is more idiomatic than the other, though.

Comment: Very similarly you can use `#then`, if you don't want to introduce a new statement: `elsif klass.method[:key].select(id: id).first.then { |result| result.nil? || result.eql?(1) }`